# How can I find where TS type is defined in my app?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I have added TS to my React/Redux app.

I use `window` object in my app like this:

```
const FB = window.FB;
```

TS throws an error:

> TypeScript error: Property 'FB' does not exist on type 'Window'.  TS2339

So type `Window` already exists in my app somehow.

How can I find where it is defined? How does TS know that type `Window` is already exists?

I want to fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

So looking at this:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation

It looks like the following declaration will *augment* the window definition:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        FB: SomeType;
    }
}
```

so now you can:

```
window.FB; //no problem
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem you can extend the Window interface and add your FB property:

```
interface WindowWithFB extends Window {
    FB: any
}

let windowWithFB: WindowWithFB = { ...window, FB: 'your FB value here' };
```

Comment: +1 
But how can I find where `Window` was defined before? Somehow TS detects it already exists.

Comment: For create-react-app, you find the implementation in `your_app/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` line 16941